# Does array_values in PHP loop through all the items?

Tags: php, arrays, optimization

I want to know if inbuilt PHP array functions such as `array_diff`, `array_keys` or `array_values` (in comparison to `array_walk`) iterate through each item or do they have an internal algorithm through which they do the computation in one go?

This is important when I want to learn how to optimise PHP scripts which handle 100,000 items.

For e.g. this method:

```
public function narrowDown($BigArray, $Column, $regex)
{
    # narrowDown to focus on columns with similar data
    $Column = array_column($BigArray, $Column);
    $Search = preg_quote($regex, '~');
    $Matched = preg_grep('~'.$Search.'~', array_combine(array_keys($BigArray), $Column));
    # recreate rows by intersecting with specified keys
    return array_intersect_key($BigArray, $Matched);
}
```

This method finds out similar rows in a specified column by regex in a multi-dimensional array.
The array has 18 columns and 100,000 items. I was thinking what should be the best way to optimise such methods.

Feel free to also advise if I should shift to a different programming language.

Comment: they iterate through each item in array

Comment: then the piece of code is very slow, I should rather do a `foreach` loop right? @IlyaBursov

Comment: yes, foreach will be single scan through array, current function performs at least 4

Comment: Just try both ways and benchmark them. Some `array_*`-functions are slower than a manual `foreach` and some are faster. It's always safest to test it yourself. Do you really need regex in this case? That will definitely slow things down

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they iterate through all items, also calls and their results are not cached in any way.

So if you will call array function twice with exactly same input, all the work will be done twice.